# Include common functions in multiple bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-18.04

Using Ubuntu 18.04. My `.bashrc` file includes the lines:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_usr_functions ]; then
    . ~/.bash_usr_functions
fi
```

In `.bash_usr_functions`, there are a bunch of user-defined functions such as:

```
function MyAmazingFunc()
{
    echo 1st param: $1
    echo Function body is complex...omitted for brevity
}
```

Now whenever a new Linux Terminal is started, typing `MyAmazingFunc 37` works as expected. Great!

Now I write a new bash script. This script would like to know about and use `AmazingFunc`. I had expected this to be automatic with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
AmazingFunc 37
```

but when I run this using `bash ./NewScript.sh` there is an error: `Command 'MyAmazingFunc' not found`.

So, I modified `NewScript.sh` to include the same lines from `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_usr_functions ]; then
    . ~/.bash_usr_functions
fi
```

This appears to work, but is very inelegant. Sourcing `.bash_usr_functions` actually launches a new, child `bash` process and runs any code in `.bash_usr_functions`! This can be verified by putting something like `echo Hello from user functions` or `read VAR1` in that file.

Is there a better method to include your own user functions in a codebase (ie. many scripts) without having to copy the entire function into every bash script or use `source`?

Comment: Sourcing does not launch a child process. It reads the sourced file in the current shell process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` to export your function to the environment of subsequently executed commands:

```
export -f MyAmazingFunc
```

---

See: `help export`

Comment: Great, that works. Added it to the `.bash_usr_functions` file (just below the definition of `MyAmazingFunc`).

Answer (score 1):

Note that '.bashrc' is only executed for 'interactive shell' - login shell, or when using (-i). If you want to be able to run your 'NewScript.sh' in other context, consider alternative implementing using 'include guard'. This will remove the dependency on the login shell.

In NewScript.sh

```
[ "$user_functions_loaded" ] || source ~/.bash_usr_functions
```

In ~/.bash_usr_functions

```
user_functions_loaded=1
func AmazingFunc ...
```

This approach eliminate the need to export individual functions - recall that if 'MyAmazingFunc' is calling other functions in ~/.bash_usr_functions, those will also have to be exported

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use BASH_ENV!
Try to add this line in your .xsessionrc file.

```
export BASH_ENV="$HOME/.bash_usr_functions"
```